# Paint component disappear after resizing window or use scrollbar

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I write a program to draw 50 rectangles after clicking OK button. But I don't uderstand why it disappears after resizing window, using scrollbar or clicking on OK again.
Here's my code (I have two classes: drawingPanel and Main)
drawingPanel.java:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class drawingPanel extends JPanel 
{
    public boolean drawIt = false;
    public int x = 140,y = 0;

    public void paintIt()
    {
        drawIt = true;
        repaint();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {

        if (drawIt == true)
            {   
                super.paintComponent(g);    
                for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++)
                {

                    g.fillRect(x, y, 50, 50);           
                    y += 70;
                }
            }

    }
}
```

Main.java:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Main extends JFrame 
{
    private drawingPanel draw = new drawingPanel();
    private JPanel controlPanel = new JPanel();
    private JButton ok = new JButton("OK");
    private JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(draw);

    public Main()
    {
        setSize(500,500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Demo");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        controlPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        controlPanel.add(ok);
        ok.addActionListener(new okListener());

        draw.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,1000));

        add(controlPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(scroll,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private class okListener implements ActionListener
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            draw.paintIt();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new Main();
    }
}
```

Please help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-initialize x and y fields within your paint component method like so that they won't keep increasing out of view each time the JPanel is drawn:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);  // move this here

    if (drawIt) {
        x = 140;  // add these guys
        y = 0;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {
            // .... etc....
```

and things should draw OK.

Other minor issues not related to your question:

- The super's painting method should always be called, so pull that out of the if block.
- Rename your drawingPanel class to be `DrawingPanel` so that it conforms to Java conventions.
- Better to change `if (drawIt == true) {` to the more simple `if (drawIt) {`
- Minor quibble: paintComponent should be `protected`, not `public`.

Comment: OMG! It worked, thanks you. But can you explain why I need to  re-initilize x and y?

Comment: @NguyenHoa: otherwise x and y keep increasing and you end up painting your rectangles, but out of the field of view.